# ValueError when training Tensorflow: setting an array element with a sequence

Tags: python, tensorflow

I was stuck on training process with ValueError.
The following are the details:

I made flags as below.

```
flags = tf.app.flags
FLAGS = flags.FLAGS

flags.DEFINE_string('train', 'train.txt', 'File name of train data')
flags.DEFINE_string('test', 'test.txt', 'File name of train data')
flags.DEFINE_string('train_dir', '/tmp/data', 'Directory to put the training data.')
flags.DEFINE_integer('max_steps', 200, 'Number of steps to run trainer.')
flags.DEFINE_integer('batch_size', 10, 'Batch size'
                     'Must divide evenly into the dataset sizes.')
flags.DEFINE_float('learning_rate', 1e-4, 'Initial learning rate.')
```

Moreover training process as below:

```
if 1==1:
        # Tensor for images
    images_placeholder = tf.placeholder("float", shape=(None, IMAGE_PIXELS))
        # Tensor for labels
        labels_placeholder = tf.placeholder("float", shape=(None, NUM_CLASSES))
        # dropout rate
        keep_prob = tf.placeholder("float")

        # call inference() 
        logits = inference(images_placeholder, keep_prob)
        # call loss()
        loss_value = loss(logits, labels_placeholder)
        # call training()
        train_op = training(loss_value, FLAGS.learning_rate)
        # calculate accuract
        acc = accuracy(logits, labels_placeholder)

        # prepare for saving
        saver = tf.train.Saver()
        # make Session
        sess = tf.Session()
        # initialize variables
        sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())
        # values on TensorBoard
        summary_op = tf.merge_all_summaries()
        summary_writer = tf.train.SummaryWriter(FLAGS.train_dir, sess.graph_def)

        # Training process
        for step in range(FLAGS.max_steps):
            for i in range(len(train_image)/FLAGS.batch_size):
                # batch_size
                batch = FLAGS.batch_size*i
                # define data in placeholder by feed dict
                sess.run(train_op, feed_dict={
                images_placeholder:train_image[batch:batch+FLAGS.batch_size],
        labels_placeholder: train_label[batch:batch+FLAGS.batch_size],
                keep_prob: 0.5})
```

When I run this code I faced following error. How to solve this problem?

```
File "CNN_model.py", line 230, in <module>
    images_placeholder: train_image[batch:batch+FLAGS.batch_size],labels_placeholder: train_label[batch:batch+FLAGS.batch_size],keep_prob: 0.5})
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 334, in run
    np_val = np.array(subfeed_val, dtype=subfeed_t.dtype.as_numpy_dtype)
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

---

I add code around train_image and train_label as following.

```
NUM_CLASSES = 5
IMAGE_SIZE = 599
IMAGE_PIXELS = IMAGE_SIZE*1*128
```

```
f = open("song_features.json")
 data = json.load(f)
 data = np.array(data)

 flatten_data = []
 flatten_label = []


 for line in range(len(data)):
     for_flat = np.array(data[line])
     flatten_data.append(for_flat.flatten().tolist())

     #label made as 1-of-K
     tmp = np.zeros(NUM_CLASSES)
     tmp[int(random.randint(0,4))] = 1
        flatten_label.append(tmp)

  #1 line training data
  train_image = np.asarray(flatten_data)
  train_label = np.asarray(flatten_label)
```

I constructing this model.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

This exception is raised when TensorFlow converts the values in the `feed_dict` into dense NumPy [ndarrays](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.ndarray.html), and will depend on what's in your `train_image` and `train_label` objects.

A common cause of these errors is when feed value is a *ragged* list: i.e. a list of lists, where the sublists have different sizes. For example:

```
>>> train_image = [[1., 2., 3.], [4., 5.]]
>>> np.array(train_image, dtype=np.float32)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

---

**EDIT:** Thanks for sharing your code to build `train_image` and `train_label`. I suspect the problem is in the creation of `train_image`, if the elements of `flatten_data` can have different lengths for each example. Try making the following modification to confirm this: `train_image = np.asarray(flatten_data, dtype=np.float32)`. If you get the same `ValueError`, you will need to pad or crop the individual rows so that they have `IMAGE_PIXELS` elements.

Comment: Thank you for your support. I added code around train_image and train_label.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the extra code! I updated the answer with some suggestions.

Comment: I tried train_image = np.asarray(flatten_data, dtype=np.float32) however, I got the same error. This time I added code around NUM_PIXELS.

Comment: Try adding `assert for_flat.flatten().shape == (NUM_PIXELS,)` before appending to `flatten_data`. That should find any images that are the wrong size.